# Enforcing noopener noreferrer with grunt-htmllint

Tags: gruntjs, static-analysis

I recently was using `create-react-app` and noticed that the `<a>` tag in `App.js` was using the `noopener noreferrer` attributes. I also noticed that scattered throughout our code-base, are `<a>` tags which do not use the above attributes.

I wanted to, using `grunt-htmllint`, add a rule that would enforce the adding of these attributes but am having trouble with the value that I should add to what I think would be `"tag-req-attr"`.

The documentation for the rule is listed [here](https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint/wiki/Options#tag-req-attr), but the usage for me is confusing. How can I set the specified `<a>` tag to include said rules?

I am looking for a way to enforce that the `rel` attribute contains both `noopener and noreferrer`e.g.:

`<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">My Link</a>`

Thanks

Comment: You probably want the [`link-req-noopener`](https://github.com/htmllint/htmllint/wiki/Options#link-req-noopener) option instead. So in the `options` object of your `grunt-htmllint` task you add `'link-req-noopener': true` . However the description for `link-rel-no-opener` states: _"If set, each `a` tag with `target="_blank"` must have a `rel="noopener"` **or** `rel="noreferrer"` attribute."_ - Intentional emphasis on "**or**", so I don't think it works with both values present.

Answer (score 0):

According to, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener, it looks like `noreferrer` handles both cases: `rel="noreferrer" attribute has the same effect, but also prevents the Referer header from being sent to the new page.`

In that case, simply using the `link-req-noopener` rule should be sufficient.

Comment: The `link-req-noopener` option fails if both `noopener` and `noreferrer` exist as values for the `rel` attribute as per the html fragment in your question.